# How to fetch a value from list of maps in terraform 0.12 based on condition

Tags: terraform

I am using Terraform 0.12. I have a data source that is returning a list of maps. Here is an example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc"
    "id": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "bcd"
    "id": "345"
  }
]
```

How to iterate over this datasource of list of maps and find if a map with key "name" and value "bcd" exists ?

this is my data source:

```
data "ibm_is_images" "custom_images" {}

locals {
  isexists = "return true/false based on above condition"
}
```

If it exists, I want to create a resource of count 0 otherwise 1

```
resource "ibm_is_image" "my_image" {
  count = local.isexists == "true" ? 0 : 1
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`contains` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/contains.html) to check whether a value is found in a list.

So now you just need to be able to turn your list of maps into a list of values matching the `name` key. In Terraform 0.12 you can use the [generalised splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) like this:

```
variable "foo" {
  default = [
    {
      "name": "abc"
      "id": "123"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcd"
      "id": "345"
    }
  ]
}

output "names" {
  value = var.foo[*].name
}
```

Applying this gives the following output:

```
names = [
  "abc",
  "bcd",
]
```

So, combining this we can do:

```
variable "foo" {
  default = [
    {
      "name": "abc"
      "id": "123"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcd"
      "id": "345"
    }
  ]
}

output "names" {
  value = var.foo[*].name
}

output "bcd_found" {
  value = contains(var.foo[*].name, "bcd")
}

output "xyz_found" {
  value = contains(var.foo[*].name, "xyz")
}
```

When this is applied we get the following:

```
bcd_found = true
names = [
  "abc",
  "bcd",
]
xyz_found = false
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for single condition. If I want to validate if the same map contains name "bcd" and id as "345", the program may not work. How should the condition be changed in this case ?

Comment: You'd need to chain the conditions with an and. Maybe ask a separate question if you're stuck with that though so your questions stay very focused and can be useful to others who might not have the same combination of problems.

Comment: Here is the answer:


locals {

 isexists = contains([for x in foo: "true" if x.name == "bcd" && x.id == "345"], "true")

}

Comment: Excellent explaination, thank you. If it's not obvious to someone, you don't need to create a local and a output, you can just use the same code directly in your terraform to validate a resource before acting on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate, if the same map contains name "bcd" and id as "345", the above program may not work. The condition should be changed in this case as

```
 locals { 
isexists = contains([for x in foo: "true" if x.name == "bcd" && x.id == "345"], "true") 
}

output "abc" {
value="${local.isexists}"
}
```